# ASP print out array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, debugging, associative

I would like to print out the data, for debugging purpose.

Data format would be like this

```
    cntryCode       = resArray("COUNTRYCODE")
    business        = resArray("BUSINESS") ' Payer's business name.
    shipToName      = resArray("SHIPTONAME")
```

the resArray consist of more than 10 records itself.

I tried to print out, but fail.

version 1 not working

```
public sub prArray (myarr)
    Dim x, ResponseData
    For x = 0 to myarr.Count
        ResponseData = ResponseData & myarr.Key(x) & " = " & myarr.Item(x) & "<br>"
    Next
    Response.Write ResponseData
end sub
```

version 2 also not working

```
public sub prArray (myarr)
    Dim x, ResponseData
    For x = 0 to UBound(myarr)
        ResponseData = ResponseData & myarr(x) & " = " & myarr(x) & "<br>"
    Next
    Response.Write ResponseData
end sub
```

I believe sure got some way to print out in classic asp

Comment: When you say "fail" - what is actually happening?

Comment: And what data type is your "resArray"?

Comment: Fail to print out any data.
it's NVP Collection object assigned into resArray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a Scripting.Dictionary no doubt.  It is not ordered use this:-

```
 Sub prArray(myArr)
     Dim key
     For Each key in myArr
         Response.Write key & " = " & myArr.Item(key) & "<br />"
     Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What type is resArray? Is it a Collection? From the first code section, it looks like you access the items by key, so it can't be a simple array..? Can you give code example of how resArray is declared and populated?

If the collection is 0 base it will be:

```
For x = 0 to myarr.Count - 1
```

If the collection is 0 base it will be:

```
For x = 1 to myarr.Count
```

If it is a basic array, and you don't know what index base it is:

```
For x = LBound(myarr) to UBound(myarr)
```